# C# Web service containing c++ managed dll reference does not work on IIS

Tags: c#, c++, web-services, iis

I have a web service built in C# which uses a managed C++ dll. This works absolutely fine in IIS Express. But when I try to use Local IIS it fails to load the assembly.

WebService (C#) has reference of Library (C++ dll) has reference of Library (C# dll).

1. **WebService Project Details** has the Platform ".Net Framework v4.5.2" and Runtime "v4.0.30319 / x86"
2. **C++ Dll Details** has the Platform ".Net Framework v4.0" and Runtime "v4.0.30319 / x86"
3. **IIS App Pool Details** has .Net Framework Version "v4.0", Enable 32-Bit Applications as "True" and Managed Pipeline Mode as "Integrated".
4. **Error Message** is "Could not load file or assembly '**.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."
5. **Folder Permissions** IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, IIS AppPool\ all these three have full access right now.

**Below is the event viewer log.**

Event Xml:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1310</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-04-28T07:18:06.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>42469</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Digvijay</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3008</Data>
    <Data>A configuration error has occurred.</Data>
    <Data>4/28/2017 12:48:06 PM</Data>
    <Data>4/28/2017 7:18:06 AM</Data>
    <Data>31199bc0e1114f6db1b89bebd5121a29</Data>
    <Data>1</Data>
    <Data>1</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Service-1-131378374852383402</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/Service</Data>
    <Data>F:\Digvijay\Projects\Service\</Data>
    <Data>DIGVIJAY</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>9496</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\AS</Data>
    <Data>ConfigurationErrorsException</Data>
    <Data>Could not load file or assembly 'LG.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean&amp; isRefAssemblyLoaded)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Could not load file or assembly 'LG.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)

</Data>
    <Data>http://localhost/Service/Service1.asmx</Data>
    <Data>/Service/Service1.asmx</Data>
    <Data>::1</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\AS</Data>
    <Data>6</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\AS</Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean&amp; isRefAssemblyLoaded)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: is your dll include in your deloyment server. another option maybe its not your c++ dll only. how can you be sure that it is your c++ dll cause the error?

Comment: another option try to register your c++ dll to system32 directory.

Comment: @reds : The dll and its dependencies are inside bin folder of the webservice on deployment server. I am sure that C++ dll is the root cause, because message says that "**.dll" or one of its dependencies are not getting loaded.

Comment: @reds : I already tried copying dlls to system32 folder. But this did not work.